# Calculating difference of dates In Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datediff

I'm trying to find out the time between certain fields in my tables. However cause I'm using Postgresql **:((** I can't use the DATEDIFF function. I can't find any clear guides/ tutorials on the net which shows how to do a similar thing in Postgres so I need help doing the same thing but in Postgres

I'm assuming this query would work if I was using a RDBMS that supported the DATEDIFF function so basically my question is how can I change this so it works using features provided by Postgresql?

```
SELECT Question.ID, 
Question.Status, COUNT (qUpdate.ID)  AS NumberofUpdates,
DATEDIFF (Question.LoggedTime,MIN(qUpdate.UpdateTime)) AS TimeBeforeFirstUpdate,
DATEDIFF(Question.LoggedTime, MAX(qUpdate.UpdateTime)) AS TimeBeforeLastUpdate
FROM qUpdate
LEFT JOIN Question ON qUpdate.qID=Question.ID
WHERE Question.Status = 'closed' AND qUpdate.Update NOT NULL
GROUP BY Question.Status, Question.ID, Question.LoggedTime;
```

If you need more info or any clarification I'll responsd ASAP.

Comment: Postgres is very feature rich. It really is worth reading through the manual.

Comment: Sorry I've never been shown that before. I'm definitely going to look at that from now on :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need a "datediff" function.

Just subtract the two dates:

```
Question.LoggedTime - MIN(qUpdate.UpdateTime)
```

In case you don't know, but all that is documented online:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: And I was struggling with the age function all this time :/

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `age(<date1>, <date2>)` function (instead of `DATEDIFF`).

This should work -

```
SELECT Question.ID, 
Question.Status, COUNT (qUpdate.ID)  AS NumberofUpdates,
age(Question.LoggedTime,MIN(qUpdate.UpdateTime)) AS TimeBeforeFirstUpdate,
age(Question.LoggedTime, MAX(qUpdate.UpdateTime)) AS TimeBeforeLastUpdate
FROM qUpdate
LEFT JOIN Question ON qUpdate.qID=Question.ID
WHERE Question.Status = 'closed' AND qUpdate.Update NOT NULL
GROUP BY Question.Status, Question.ID, Question.LoggedTime;
```

Note, if psql gives you this error - `ERROR:  date/time field value out of range`, then you would need to choose an appropriate `datestyle`.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT extract(year from age('2014-01-23', '1985-08-27'));
-- returns 28 years, my current age.
```

Answer (score 0):

this gives you the time diff in seconds:

```
select extract(epoch from to_date::timestamp - from_date::timestamp)
```