# Ruby on Rails: How to get all the records and sort it by the lowest days difference of two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using postgresql. I have one table the Shipments table and I have two date columns on the table called arrival_date and release_date, what I wanted to do is to get all the record and sort it according to the lowest days difference of arrival_date and release_date, for example:

```
Arrival Date, Released Date
2017-06-04,   2017-06-30
2017-05-02,   2017-05-05
```

So in this example the days difference of first record is 26 days and the second one is 3 days, so the second record should be the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to subtract the two dates using Postgres:

`ordered_shipments = Shipment.order("(arrival_date - released_date) ASC")`

This will subtract the Unix timestamps of the two dates and sort the difference in ascending order.

I got inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10065916/2430657).

Comment: thanks for this answer! how about if there are two records with the same days difference, for example 2 records have the same days difference lets say 2 days difference, I want to get those two records with the same days diffrence

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need improve your query in postgres

in example

```
Table
id   |  dateA   |   dateB

select dateA, dateB, age(timestamp dateA, timestamp dateB) diffdate from Table order by diffdate desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `sort_by!` method:

```
Shipment.all.sort_by!{ |shipment| shipment.released_date - shipment.arrival_date }
```